# How should end users respond to Earthlink's "Allowed Sender" feature when blocked by policy?

Tags: email, spam, corporate-policy, antimalware

Some of our users are requested to click on an [Earthlink antispam URL](http://www.earthlink.net/webmail/help/earthlink/en_US/spamblocker/allow_senders.html) below

```
https://webmail.pas.earthlink.net/wam/addme?a=USERNAME@earthlink.net&id=<SOME GUID>
```

However our firewall policy is blocking this as category "WebMail".

What is the correct way to handle this situation?  should I allow this URL to pass as an exception, possibly encouraging this behavior?

I'm concerned about encouraging users to click on hyperlinks from unknown senders, or in email in general.  But since the user claims to know who this is, I'm less concerned about that in this specific instance.

Does anyone have thoughtful guidance on how to handle this?

Comment: @schroeder I'm interested in managing user behavior, not technical

Comment: Are you discussing allowing this for a specific `USERNAME` or for a wildcard? Where did they get this URL from?